# Can these Haskell operations be presented as piecewise mathematical functions?

Tags: functions, notation, recursion, programming

I am researching the idea from [O'Donnell,Hall and Page](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220695320_Discrete_mathematics_using_a_computer_2_ed) that

> Haskell serves both as a formal, mathematical notation, and as a
> practical and powerful programming language

See also the [The Haskell Road to Logic, Maths and Programming](https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/d.j.n.vaneijck2/HR/) by
Jan van Eijck.

Given the Haskell code in Listing 1, is it possible to represent the two operations $\mathsf{eq}$  and $\mathsf{plus}$ as piecewise mathematical functions?

**Listing 1**

```
    -- Peano numbers
    data Nat = Zero | Suc Nat deriving Show 
    -- Equality
    eq :: Nat -> Nat -> Bool
    eq Zero Zero = True
    eq (Suc x) (Suc y) = eq x y
    eq _ _ = False
    
    plus :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
    plus x Zero =  x
    plus x (Suc y) = Suc (plus x y)
```

My assumption is that patterns in Haskell function definitions are like mathematical piecewise functions. The arguments on left hand side of each Haskell equation, when compared to some *value*, represents the condition for each mathematical case.  Here are my attempts:

\begin{align*}
\forall x,y \in \mathbb{N}~ \colon \mathsf{eq}(x,y) = \begin{cases}
True & \text{if $x=Zero \land y=Zero$}, \\
\mathsf{eq}(x',y') & \text{if $ x = \mathsf{Suc}(x') \land y = \mathsf{Suc}(y')$}, \\
False & \text{otherwise}.  \\
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\forall x,y \in \mathbb{N} ~\colon \mathsf{plus}(x,y) = \begin{cases}
x & \text{if $y=Zero$}, \\
\mathsf{Suc}(\mathsf{plus}(x,y'))  & \text{if $y = \mathsf{Suc}(y')$}. \\
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Are these attempts reasonable? Are there alternative mathematical notations for these recursive function definitions?

Comment: Looks correct to me. Another way to look at is recursive/inductive definitions.

Comment: I think the last line of your second attempt should be $\mathrm{Suc}(\mathrm{plus}(x, y')) \quad \mathrm{if}\,\, y = \mathrm{Suc}(y')$.

Comment: @Rushy Thanks, I have made your suggested correction.

Comment: Since you are asking for *mathematical* notation, you should write $x\in \Bbb N$ instead of $x:\Bbb N$

Comment: @P OT: I tried some code from  O'Donnell's book and tried some examples but had a lot of problems. So where did you find an appropriate Haskell interpeter?

Comment: @miracle173 If you want a simple compact version of Haskell for learning purposes then [HUGS](https://www.haskell.org/hugs/pages/downloading.htm) is fine.  For real developement [GHCI](https://www.haskell.org/) is probably better. The above program runs in both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* write it like that, though the version you will find in most texts in mathematical logic is simply

> $$ \begin{align}
> x + 0 &= x \\
> x + Sy &= S(x+y)
> \end{align} $$

which looks a lot more like the Haskell definition of `plus`. This is no coincidence: the *origin* of Haskell's pattern-matching function definitions is a wish to mimic *existing* mathematical notation.

The big-curly-bracket notation in mathematics corresponds more directly to Haskell's notion of *guards*.

---

The situation with `eq` is not as straightforward. Again your attempt is not *wrong*, but it doesn't really look like *idiomatic* mathematics.

This is mostly the fault of the mathematical tradition that insists on distinguishing syntactically between *claims* (which can either be true or not) and *expressions* (which produce values). Programming languages tend to consider such a distinction superfluous and just handle claims as expressions that happen to produce truth values as results.

In most mathematical contexts, one wouldn't even attempt to write the `eq` purely symbolically, but would instead use prose, something like

> The relation $\equiv$ is defined recursively by
>
> 1. $0\equiv0$.
> 2. $Sx \equiv Sy$ iff $x\equiv y$.
> 3. Nothing else is related by $\equiv$.

In *theoretical computer science*, sitting halfway between mathematics and programming, it is common to notate such definitions symbolically as an *inference system* which looks like

> $$ \frac{}{0 \equiv 0} \qquad \frac{x\equiv y}{Sx\equiv Sy} $$

But this will not be generally recognized by most non-logician mathematicians.